# Can an NIS user be a member of a local group?

Tags: linux

I have a Linux box which is part of an NIS setup which I cannot administer.  My login on the Linux box assigned to me has sudo privileges.  I need to setup a local group, and make my NIS user a member of the local group.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the same way you'd add a local user, for example:

```
sudo groupadd local_group
sudo gpasswd -a nis_user local_group
```